# Line height changes all the time in NSTextView on Mac when you typing Chinese characters continuously

Tags: nstextview

On mac client, NSTextView.The text height jitters when continuously entering Chinese or other languages except English in NSTextView, for other languages like English, will not happen. For Chinese, if a blank or emoji or a number input, the text will not jitter any more. See the .gif for more detail. Anyone knows the solution for it? A lot of thanks for your help!

As you typing Chinese characters, the font height changes all the time. See the .gif attachment, pls.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xtxzi.gif)

Comment: Are you setting the line height?

Comment: Does TextEdit have the same problem?

Comment: @Bill NO, this happen only when input Chinese continuously. If I input a blank, then the text height will keep normal. Like the system "Notes" APP,  the same behavior as I described.

Comment: @Willeke TextEdit does not have the same problem. But "Notes" App from system has the same problem on 
Mac os 10.15 when input Chinese continuously.

Comment: Have you tried a different font or size?

Comment: @Willeke Yes. I have tried different size, but the same behavior.